# nested linearlayout not appearing..gives black space

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Hi i am new to android programming. In my app I have nested layouts. following is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context="com.tdapps.play_video.MainActivity"
android:background="?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground">
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgoverlay">

            <Button
                android:text="Import Image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Importimage"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#00ffff"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/vignette">

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/vseekbar"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Grayscale"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00ffff"
                android:text="Grayscale"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Negative"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00ffff"
                android:text="Negative"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>






        <HorizontalScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/blurview">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BilateralFilter"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Bilateral"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/median"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Median"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blur1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Blur Level 1"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"


                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blur2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Blur Level 2"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"


                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blur3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Blur Level 3"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blur4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Blur Level 4"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blur5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Blur Level 5"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/blur6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Blur Level 6"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Brightness"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00ffff"
                android:text="Brightness"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Contrast"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00ffff"
                android:text="Contrast"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00ffff"
                android:max="255" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView

            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Lightning"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Lightning"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Filter"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Filter"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Crop"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Crop"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Color"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Color"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Rotate"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Rotate"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"

                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Vignette"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Vignette"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ImgOverlay"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Image Overlay"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/PutText"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#00ffff"
                    android:text="Put Text"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

so when I set setvisibility for both filter and light layouts they appears and works fine. but when i set setvisibility for color layout it shows blank space for that layout(i mean image view exists . the layout under the imageview is not appearing. but getvisibility tells that layout is visible). I tried changing layout width,height with wrap content,match parent but still giving the same result. why this linear layout (for "color") is not appearing? how to solve this. thanks

Comment: why down vote :( :( ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can remove the `RelativeLayout` to simplify your XML.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for quick reply.  i guess you are talking about relativelayout that contains all the linearlayouts, horizontal scroll views etc.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, the RelativeLayout contains a LinearLayout which in turn contains everything else. The outer RelativeLayout is unnecessary.

Comment: Your color layout is under main(HorizontalScrollView), light and blurview layout. Thats why you cant see the color layout. Tell me what is your requirement?

Comment: @tahsinRupam mm i am sorry i don't get it. what you mean by "Your color layout is under main(HorizontalScrollView), light and blurview layout" ?. my requirement is when i set visibility of main layout to invisible and visibility of color layout to visible the main layout must disappear and and color layout must appear.

Comment: wow that worked. Very much thank you.... !!! I wish I could mark your comment as an answer . thanks so much again.

Comment: My pleasure. Ok, then I am adding this as an answer. You can then mark the answer as accepted. It may help others in future.

Comment: done........!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks you for your appreciation....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you set main layout invisible, light and blurview layouts are still above color layout. RelativeLayout works as stacks. The later layouts appear first. I copied your codes. I set main, light and blurview invisible, then the color layout appeared.

Here is the color layout.

[image]